# Generate div columns using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

following code on jsfiddle:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="b">test1</div>
    <div class="b">test2</div>
    <div class="b">test3</div>
    <div class="b">test4</div>
    <div class="b">test5</div>
    <div class="b">test6</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.b {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 2px;
    float:left;
    width: calc(16.7% - 10px);
    height:400px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/329vcLLc/ does work, it shows 5 columns the way I would like them to be formatted.

I must loop over an array to generate the divs according to the number of elements of the div. I thought I could use the `append()` function, what do you think? and how can I set the width property for each div (cause it depends on the number of columns)

any ideas?

Comment: What does "generate divs according to the number of elements of the divs" mean? If I have `<div><p></p></div>` should it generate one div?

Answer (score 0):

According to your provided css you can do something like this:

```
var divs = ['a','b','c','d','e', 'f', 'g'];
var con_width = parseInt($('#container').width()); //get the width of the container
var width = (con_width / divs.length) - 10; //divide trough the number of divs, 
//subtract 10 to make them fit

$.each(divs, function(index, value){
    var div = $('<div />').addClass('b').text(value).css('width', width + 'px'); //generate new div
    $('#container').append(div); //append it to the container
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jjzvhqke/)

**Reference**

[.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

[.width()](https://api.jquery.com/width/)

[.css()](https://api.jquery.com/css/)

[.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

[.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what the number of the divs depends on, but if you need to generate some known number of divs you may do this:

```js
var n=8;
var $cont=$('#container');
for(var i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    var d=$('<div>').addClass('b').html('test '+(i)).css('width', 'calc('+(100/n)+'% - 10px)');
    $cont.append(d);
}
```

```css
.b {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 2px;
    float:left;
    height:400px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"> 
</div>
```